# Is there any trick to activate any Website Features of Site Collection without having the permissions for it?

Tags: features

I would like to activate certain SharePoint Site Collection features, but I do not have the required Admin rights for that. Is there any trick to do this? May be a bit a cheeky question focused to the person who is responsible for the Site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you don't have the permission to do so, you cannot enable the feature. Ask your site collection administrators or a farm admin to do it for you if it is something you need for your site.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. He's on holidays, so I have to wait till he's back :)